# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/blabla/bla/config Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, tomcat, wamp

I'm running a server application in Tomcat 7 on port 8081 of my localhost and a client js-application in wamp (think thats port 80). When I try to run it (in chrome), i'm getting this error in my console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/blabla/bla/config Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it? The code runs fine if I check with unit test and debugging. The error is thrown when the response reaches the client

If I just go to `http://localhost:8081/blabla/bla/config` in my browser, I get the right response in JSON

Comment: I would recommend looking up access control allow origin. Basically you are only allowed make xhr requests to the same origin as the parent page, including the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you neeed take a look at CORS at W3C:http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/

Your site (the origin) need to aswer with a access-control-allow-origin response header to be allowed. You need to add to your server.

http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header

This question can help too: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383109/access-control-allow-origin-in-tomcat)

Comment: That last link helped me, it works fine now