# Cross-origin resource sharing for Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, cors

I am new to Cross-origin resource sharing and I want to enable it in a Tomcat 7.0.39 server. Anybody can give me some hint how can this be achieved?

I want to set the header universally for all requests, and to allow all origins (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *)

Wich file should i add it?

Comment: So, do the answers to that question not help?

Comment: no, it doesn't work to me

Comment: I highly doubt that the very well known Java CORS implementation is broken. Did you even read the documentation at http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a servlet filter to set the CORS headers in Tomcat. See a sample filter implementation on [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296145/set-header-in-tomcat/16307321#16307321/)