# Is there a way to add X-Frame-Options header to a JavaScript file served through Tomcat?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, xss, assets, x-frame-options

Can I add X-Frame-Options header to a JavaScript file served through Tomcat? I am adding the header to all jsps programmatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set header in Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296145/set-header-in-tomcat)

Comment: That header has no effect on JS files.

Answer (score 0):

A hack (but it'll solve your problem cleanly) is to serve the .js file as a JSP.  Literally rename yourfile.js to yourfile.jsp, then change the script-src that loads it into your page.  Any modern browser (I've checked, and used this solution in production environments) will load a .jsp file via script-src.  I did this for the same reason you are: being able to set response headers on .js files.