# Apache Tomcat config files, Windows Server 2012, not running as service

Tags: tomcat, cors

I'm running Apache Tomcat on Windows Server 2012.  All I did was download the zip file, open it on the desktop and i start/stop everything from there.

I'm trying to access some web services running on the server from a javascript program running on my dev machine.  My dev machine and the server running apache are not on the same network and i am getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load service-call-snipped-for-brevity Response 
to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is 
therefore not allowed access.
```

I've read that i have to add:

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

to the httpd.conf file and I create it in the apache install conf dir (remember apache was "installed" by my unzipping the downloaded zip file to my desktop) and if it doesn't exist I can create it.

Excellent!

Except when I do all that and restart Apache Tomcat I still get the same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Apache _Tomcat_ does not use a httpd.conf, Apache _Webserver_ does. http://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS in apache tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526146/how-to-enable-cors-in-apache-tomcat)

Comment: @Marged how do i mark your answer as correct?

Comment: You can't because it is only a comment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tomcat does not use a httpd.conf, Apache Webserver does.

There are plenty of answers that tell you how to configure Tomcat for CORS, for example [How to enable CORS in apache tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526146/how-to-enable-cors-in-apache-tomcat)