# How to handle "Response to preflight request doesn't pass No Access-control-Allow-Origin header is present on requested resource " from angular in BE

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, tomcat

I'm sending this request from Angular UI:

```
'Accept':'multipart/form-data',
'Access-Control-Allow-Crendentails':'true',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Method':'POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Authorization,Content-Type'
```

Iv'e got the following error:

```
Orgin'http://localhost ' is therefore not allowed
```

The webserver is Apache Tomcat. How can I handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following two links to solve your problem:

1. [Set CORS header in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296145/set-cors-header-in-tomcat)
2. [How to enable CORS in apache tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526146/how-to-enable-cors-in-apache-tomcat)