# where should i add response.addHeader?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Where should i add this function  response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); to avoid the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

This is my ajax function.Now I can I get ajax response only from www.myspansalon.com..I want response from myspansalon.com.

```js
<script>
function getdetails(rate){

var itemid=jQuery("#itemid").val();
var userid=jQuery("#userid").val();
jQuery("#clear").show();
jQuery("#uservote").text('loading...');
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"http://www.myspansalon.com/joomla/index.php?option=com_flexicontent&format=raw&task=myvoting",
       
    data: {item_id:itemid, user_id:userid, rating:rate }
    }).done(function(result){
     
 jQuery("#uservote").text(result);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery

Comment: The server sends response headers, not the client.

Comment: You can't get around the same-origin policy in the client. If you can't change the server to send that header, you need to use a proxy in your own domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try `xhr.setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`, please check your modified code below. I'm not sure whether it will work, because basically the response header is set in the server not in the client.

```
<script >
function getdetails(rate) {

    var itemid = jQuery("#itemid").val();
    var userid = jQuery("#userid").val();
    jQuery("#clear").show();
    jQuery("#uservote").text('loading...');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.myspansalon.com/joomla/index.php?option=com_flexicontent&format=raw&task=myvoting",

        data: {
            item_id: itemid,
            user_id: userid,
            rating: rate
        },
        success: function (response, status, xhr) {
            xhr.setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (status == "success") {
                alert(response);
            } else {
                alert(status + ' - ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    }).done(function (result) {

        jQuery("#uservote").text(result);
    });
} < /script>
```

**To set response header in the server side :-**

If the webservice website is developed in java and it's using tomcat as the server then you can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296145/set-header-in-tomcat). In a java web application you can do it with `javax.servlet.Filter` class implementation (independent of the server). But, having seen the *url* used in the code you posted, it seems to be *php*, so you may [follow this link](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch07_05.htm).

Comment: @Visruth..its not working..:(..how can I set response header in the server?

Answer (score 0):

First you are trying to access another domain by AJAX so [`SOP` (Same-origin policy)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) should be enable on another domain.

you can add `header` in `beforeSend` event, see below

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('x-my-custom-header', 'some value');
    }
```

Comment: This won't work. This is a response header, not a request header. It has to be sent by the server.

Comment: right @Barmar but he will need to enable (Same-origin policy) on server to access domain..