# Cross-Origin Request blocked when trying to request page from apex

Tags: javascript, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, apex

I'm trying to call a page outside of apex, but it isn't working. When I click a button in apex a dynamic action is triggered. It is a javascript block which has the following code:

```
var xmlhttp;
var name = document.getElementById('P1_X').value;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
  // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
}
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://92.109.55.51:7070/xander/rest/templates/" + name,true);

xmlhttp.send();
```

I get the following error **without** the `setRequestHeader` lines:
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://92.109.55.51:7070/xander/rest/templates/Test1. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

I've looked around the internet and tried at things to my header([Source](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)) as shown in the code, but I don't know where to put the header part. Currently I'm getting:
`InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`

How do I get apex to get the information from the other page with a dynamic action?

Comment: You can not set CORS on the clientside....That is what the serverside needs to provide!

Comment: @epascarello So the serverside has to add those options to the header?

Comment: That is how CORS works. They have to give you permission to read the data.

Comment: The target server is a java application with rest services(Dynamic web project) on a tomcat server. Do I have to add the header options to the tomcatserver or to the java files?

Comment: The problem is solved. with your comments on the problem and a little help from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296145/set-header-in-tomcat/16307321) its working. Except for firefox... weird. but thx:)