# Simulate Shoutcast `ICY 200 OK` response with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

How to make my servlet respond with `ICY 200 OK` instead of `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, like `Shoutcast` servers do? I can only think of using plain tcp sockets on a separate port.

Comment: Write to header your custom information rather than changing existing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296145/set-header-in-tomcat