# Doing CORS manually

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, cors

I'm trying to debug my web app, 
I have a POST request. (using ajax, with xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } ). dataType is 'application/json', my server is tomcat and i set my "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header manually to "http://localhost:8080".

other headers:
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-request-verification-token");

Cant get this to work. this is the error i get:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/MysServlet. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'http://localhost:8080').

thanks ahead!

Comment: Why you have response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"); , are you needing any user credential to access the url

Comment: In case you're using tomcat 7+, have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296145/set-cors-header-in-tomcat)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a configuration that apply to all your requests add in your `web.xml` the following filter:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>originfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>it.damore.web.ApiOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>originfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

This is the ApiOriginFilter class:

```java
 public class ApiOriginFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! added this and it worked!
(Removed the manual response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");)



<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>