# CORS - Calling rest services on Tomcat from angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome, tomcat, cors

I am trying to call REST services deployed on Tomcat 8 from Angular 4. Since both these are running on separate domains, CORS issue is expected. So, in the tomcat/conf/web.xml, I have added the below filter

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Authorization,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is how I am sending the GET request from Angular

```
var basicOptions:RequestOptionsArgs = {
  url: 'http://server3:7000/myrest/info',
  method: RequestMethod.Get,
  search: null,
  headers: new Headers(
    {'Authorization': 'Basic AG1hZG1pbjpkZW1vLmRlbW8=' },
    ),
  body: null
};

basicOptions.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

var reqOptions = new RequestOptions(basicOptions);
var req = new Request(reqOptions);
return this.http.request( req );
```

Since, I am sending the Authorization header, it is also added in the 'cors.allowed.headers' param in Tomcat.

When I call the REST service from Chrome, it always gives me a 'Invalid CORS request' error (Network tab -> Preview). Below is the error in browser console

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server3:7000/myrest/info. Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Is there something else that I need to do to make it work?

Comment: This is not related to Angular. The server needs to be configured to support CORS requests and respond with required headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Günter Zöchbauer is right. It is not related to Angular. Even with the filter you added, the server is not configure to accept requests from other domains. To configure your server you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296145/set-cors-header-in-tomcat/18850438#18850438)

Notice that you have a preflight request because you send custom http headers (see the picture below).

[image]