# Tomcat CORS filter settings error on re-direct running Spring

Tags: angularjs, spring, apache, tomcat, cors

I have an error which I understand is down to the CORS policy to prevent potential security risks.

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and Fetch follow the same-origin policy. So, a web application using XMLHttpRequest or Fetch could only make HTTP requests to its own domain. To improve web applications, developers asked browser vendors to allow cross-domain requests.

I am running my AngularJS application on `Apache (localhost)` and am attempting to access information from the back-end running `Spring` on `Tomcat(localhost:8080)`. I have read a number of threads, one being '[Set CORS header in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296145/set-cors-header-in-tomcat/18850438#18850438)', which have informed me of adding configuration to Tomcat's `.config` file, as so:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>http://localhost</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

An error is still returned informing me:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/p3sweb/rest-patents/. Redirect from 'http://localhost:8080/p3sweb/rest-patents/' to 'http://localhost:8080/p3sweb/login;jsessionid=2658E20C637694D2154C7EEDF9875B89' has been blocked by /#!/patents:1  CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

The part that says `been blocked by /#!/patents:1` has me wondering whether there is any other configuration I have to do on the `Apache` server.

***Question***

What configuration do I have to add in order to make a request from the domain `localhost` to `localhost:8080/p3sweb/rest-patents/`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you solve this

Comment: In the end transferring my files to localhost:8080 (tomcat)