# CORS not working after I copied the instance

Tags: java, tomcat, cors, tomcat7

I have a running instance with tomcat 7 and java app. I wanted to make a copy of the instance. in Amazon, I clicked "create image", and launched a new instance from it. after that, i tried to work with the new instance. when i make simple requests it works, but when i try from a browser i get CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxx/getConfiguration' from origin 'http://xxxxxx:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

nothing has changed in my server or my front-end configuration. when i work with the old server it works. the cors filter is the same:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Last-Modified, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: please add   `<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>` to your filter and let me know it works or not

Comment: @Spara not working

Comment: [this](https://github.com/quickhack/tomcat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/filters/CorsFilter.java) is CorsFilter of tomcat. and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzud1.png) is cors flowchart. maybe reading them help you to resolve the problem

Comment: @Spara but this already works. what can change when i copy an instance?

Comment: Yeah I know thats kind of strange event!

Comment: @MosheShaham Check for any hardcoded URL calling to previous server? You can also check the access logs of frontend server, If you are receiving the request on copied server or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the init parameter names that you used

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

and [configuration reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter/Introduction) documentation of Tomcat 7. You are spelling them incorrectly.

The default value of `cors.allowed.origins` was changed in May 2018 (for Tomcat 7.0.89, 8.5.32, 9.0.9) to address CVE-2018-8014 ([bug 62343](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62343)).

Comment: this answer is accurate. for some reason, the tomcat version was upgraded from under 7.0.89 to above 7.0.89 - so the parameters names indeed changed!

Answer (score 0):

Did you your javascript/html/css in same server with your old instance ?

When browser do some API call, if the API address is in different server/domain with javascript path, browser will check CORS header of API to ensure this server allow cross-origin request. In old instance, everything are same place, so no need to do. But in new instances, your app need to return CORS header to client.

You can see this question to know how to add CORS header to your application in Tomcat:

[Set CORS header in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296145/set-cors-header-in-tomcat)