# JasperReports Server 8.0.0 Deployed on Tomcat CORS Errors

Tags: tomcat, cors, jasperserver

When calling any of the REST web services from my Angular front-end application (or via cURL), I receive a CORS error in the console window.

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://<base_url>:8083/jasperserver/rest_v2/login?j_username=username&j_password=password' from origin 'http://<base_url>' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

I have tried other endpoints in the web services library, such as:

- {{jasper_url}}/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources?type=reportUnit
- {{jasper_url}}/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/Reports/Case_Status.html?report_date=2022-03-07
- {{jasper_url}}/jasperserver/rest_v2/serverInfo

I have the same issue when running Angular locally or on the server where JasperReports Server is installed.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/cors-visualizejs) to whitelist my server's domain, and I've also tried to whitelist all domains with "*", but with no luck, even after restarting Tomcat.

[image]

I have updated the apache-tomcat/conf/web.xml with the below config by following the answer from this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296145/set-cors-header-in-tomcat), but with no luck, even after restarting Tomcat.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

AFter the above filter was applied to Tomcat, I can confirm by using cURL to test that "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" is returned for http://base_url:8083, but NOT for http://base_url:8083/jasperserver. This leads me to believe that my problem is purely with JasperReports Server, and not with Tomcat at all.

[image]

Upon further investigation as detailed in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nfk3vdWvexY) by Dr. Jaspersoft, an OPTIONS request returns a 403, but a GET request returns a 200 and "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

[image]

I've since removed the CORS filter from apache-tomcat/conf/web.xml and rather added a similar one directly to the jasperserver web app (apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/web.xml), where base_url is obviously replaced with teh server's URL.

```
   <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>http://base_url, https://base_url, http://localhost:8080</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE,PATCH</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Cache-Control,X-Suppress-Basic,Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Pragma,accept-timezone,withCredentials,X-Remote-Domain,X-Is-Visualize,x-jrs-base-url,Content-Disposition,Content-Description,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Connection,Host,authorization,Options</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>300</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The above CORS configuration yielded positive results when testing with cURL on the {{jasper_url}}/jasperserver/rest_v2/serverInfo endpoint, but other endpoints that require credentials are still giving CORS errors.

[image]

I can't be the only one struggling with this, so if anyone else has resolved CORS errors with later versions of JasperReports Server, please help out!

A an aside, I'm using NGINX and thought that I may be able to use that to prevent the CORS errors, simlar to the answers in [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx). However, I have not gone that far as I'm sure there must be an easier way to do this by configuring JasperReports Server.

Server information

- Operating system: Linux Debian 11
- JasperReports version: 8.0.0
- Tomcat version: 9.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After MUCH trial and error, I've somewhat resolved the error.

I added the following to the /apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <!--  Update allowed origins and remove localhost for non-dev environments -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>http://dev.greydom.com, https://dev.greydom.com, http://localhost:8080</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE,PATCH</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Cache-Control,X-Suppress-Basic,Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Pragma,accept-timezone,withCredentials,X-Remote-Domain,X-Is-Visualize,x-jrs-base-url,Content-Disposition,Content-Description,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Connection,Host,Authorization,Options</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>300</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My only mistake was that I needed a capital A for Authorized in allowed headers.

I can now access the web services with no CORS errors

Comment: how did you make it work?.. when i add the cors filter. the CSRF token is not working..

Comment: @PICTD.RUFY The above web.xml was used as it is here

Comment: I think the problem is with nginx reverse proxy.. instead of enabling cors in jasperserver i manage to make it work by enabling cors via nginx

Comment: @PICTD.RUFY I don't think so. I'm using just Tomcat (no reverse proxy) and the problem persists. I was able to solve it with the answer anyway, but according to the docs, this config is not required after version 7.5

Comment: Did you have to turn off anti-CSRF? Cors starts working, but "Failed to retrieve CSRF token" appears

Comment: No I didn't turn off anti-CSRF

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work with my installation (8.2.0, jasperserver-pro). CSRF protection always fails when this cors where configured.

However, I found something similar but at the jasper configuration lvl.
In the `WEB-INF/applicationContext-security-web.xml` search for `<bean id="corsProcessor"`, and here you can configure (as I assume) any header. I successfully configured `Content-Security-Policy` headers like below (with even working policy - I mean almost working because I used it to prevent loading any website into the dashboard)

```xml
                <entry key="Content-Security-Policy">
                    <util:list>
                        <value>.*</value>
                    </util:list>
                </entry>
```

```xml
                <entry key="Content-Security-Policy">
                    <util:list>
                        <value>default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'</value>
                    </util:list>
                </entry>
```

However, when I add CORS headers it fails - any given Origin was added to cors headers...