# CORS filter tomcat 7 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: apache, tomcat7, cors

I am using the following configuration in my tomcat7 conf/web.xml

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
  <param-value>*</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
  <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
  <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Last-Modified</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
  <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>

</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My apache webserver sends request to tomcat rest api. APache webserver is running on port 8005 and tomcat is running on 8080. So request goes from mydomain.com:8085/index.php/kop to mydomain.com:8080/webiste-1.0/rest-api/product. I am getting

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://x.x.x.x:8085' is    therefore not allowed access.
```

Following is the request header from chrome:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Cache-Control:no-cache
Origin:http://x.x.x.x:8085
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://x.x.x.x:8085/html/index.php/kop_och_salj
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153    Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers:
Content Length: "0"
Date: "Wed, 18 Jun 2014 12:02:11 GMT"
Server: "Apache-Coyote/1.1"

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing anything?

Comment: I have added Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" to my apache web server as well and curl shows the Header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"  but still i get the same error

Comment: i have the exact same problem

Comment: Apache Tomcat includes support for CORS - Starting from Tomcat version 7.0.41 - my problem was I installed tomcat 7 by using apt-get install tomcat7 on ubuntu 12.04 release and it installed older version than 7.0.41. Once I installed tomcat manually 7.0.54, cors filter worked.

Comment: @wazzz this is very interesting, and I suggest you reply to yourself, like explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access-Control-Allow-Origin: \* in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383109/access-control-allow-origin-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Apache Tomcat includes support for CORS - Starting from Tomcat version 7.0.41 - my problem was I installed tomcat 7 by using apt-get install tomcat7 on ubuntu 12.04 release and it installed older version than 7.0.41. Once I installed tomcat manually 7.0.54, cors filter worked