# How to enable cors issue in Angular2 with Backend as Liferay server

Tags: java, angular, cors, liferay-6

I am new to Angular2. I have to create new Angular application and Need to use services from Liferay server.

But When I call the Service using below code, it is giving Cors error.

```
var headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();   

    this.http.get(localStorage.getItem('domainName')+'/service-name', {headers: headers})
        .subscribe(response => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            console.log('Response'+response.json());
    });
```

My backend method is GET and I have added Cors filter property in my /webapps/Root/web.xml file

BUt in browser console it is giving below error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9080/service-name. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: is your server also allowing CORS requests? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383109/access-control-allow-origin-in-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

This error comes up when the backend's response does not have the necessary `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Please double check that the backend's headers are properly configured. Also, the frontend's request does not have to have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header ever.